# 3D Plot for a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x

[image: ![enter image description here]

**I am trying to plot a a DataFrame in 3D. What is that I am doing wrong? **

```
x = drop_1row_df.columns.tolist()
print(x)

y = drop_1row_df.index.strftime("%d %b, %Y").tolist()
print(y)

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = drop_1row_df
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```